# Requirements for a WS to be considered restful

Tags: web-services, rest, constraints

in an answer from [What gets classified as a RESTful Web Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261954/what-gets-classified-as-a-restful-web-service) it is stated:

> There are a number of other constraints that a service must respect in order to be considered RESTful

Where could I find the list of constraints?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [REST dissertation](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) covers all the constraints.  Specifically, they are listed in [this](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_derivation.gif) diagram.